# Why does GET work, but DELETE and POST do not work (error:404) in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, post, http-delete

Actually my http works, `get` worked, but `delete` and `post` did not work. 
What do you think I do?

It is my component, I do not know why it didn't work

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { HttpService } from '../http.service';

@Component({
      selector: 'app-http',
      templateUrl: './http.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./http.component.css']
})

export class HttpComponent implements OnInit {

      followers = [];
      constructor(private hService: HttpService,
        private http: Http
      ) { }

      private url: string = "./app/http/followers.json";


      ngOnInit() {
        this.http.get(this.url)
          .map((response: Response) => response.json())
          .subscribe(user=>this.followers=user)

      }

      createpost(input: HTMLInputElement) {
        let name = { name: input.value };
        input.value = '';

        this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify("name"))
          .subscribe(response => {
            name = response.json();
            this.followers.splice(0, 0, name);
          });
      }
      deletepost() {
        this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + "id")
          .subscribe(response => {
            let index = this.followers.indexOf("id");
            this.followers.splice(index, 1);
          });

      }


    }
```

It is my http>follower.json

[image: example-data]

**Component.html**

```
<div>

  <h2>Followers list</h2>
  <input type="text" #name (keyup.enter)="createpost(name)" class="list-control">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="createpost(name)">Add to fallowers</button>


  <ul class="list-group">
    <li *ngFor="let follower of followers" class="list-group-item">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deletepost(name)">UnFollow</button>
      {{follower.name}} 

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like your URL is pointing to a static file, so DELETE and POST requests will not work. You would need to code these yourself in the backend

Comment: private url: string = "./app/http/followers.json"; url is incorrect

Comment: as @user184994 already said, you cannot execute any HTTP method on static files besides `GET` method, which will just return a content of your static file. To achieve your goal, you can use json-server (https://github.com/typicode/json-server) library, which will allow you to execute POST and DELETE on your JSON file. Please note, that it will be run on different port with CORS enabled by default. After installing this node module, just point to your JSON as DB source: `json-server PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE/followers.json`